# CKFinder 3 - browser is blank

Tags: php, ckfinder3

Im using CKFinder 3 integrated with CKEditor 4.

I can upload an image without issue, but when clicking 'browse' I see a blank pop up. I have turned error reporting on but nothing is shown.

[image]

Code

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor',
{

filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by integrated with CKE4?

The sample below shows the configuration code that can be used to insert a CKEditor 4 instance with CKFinder integrated. The browse and upload paths for images are configured separately from CKFinder default paths.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
});
```

Remember to change the /ckfinder/ path in the above URLs if you installed CKFinder in a different location.

Note: The filebrowser*UploadUrl paths in CKFinder 2.x and CKFinder 3.x are different.

What are the plugins that you are using?

Open your browser console to see if there is any error in there. You can press F12 in your browser and click on the console tab.

Also enable